# Exporting a dataset, but the datatables values don't show up

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I'm exporting a dataset to xml file like this

```
DataAccess.Instance.TabelasPsis.WriteXml(@"C:\tabelapsis.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

But when i open the xml file created, it doesn't have the values of the tables included in "TabelasPsis" dataset

By the way i have the dataset created in another class so it gets public and every form can acess it

```
public DataSet TabelasPsis { get; set; }

public DataTable tabelapsisEN11 { get; set; }
public DataTable tabelapsisEN13 { get; set; }
public DataTable tabelapsisEN14 { get; set; }
public DataTable tabelapsisEN15 { get; set; }
public DataTable tabelapsisEN12 { get; set; }

// Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
// not to mark type as beforefieldinit
static DataAccess()
{
}

DataAccess()
{

    this.TabelasPsis = new DataSet("Tabelaspsis");
    this.tabelapsisEN11 = new DataTable("tabelapsisEN11");
    this.tabelapsisEN13 = new DataTable("tabelapsisEN13");
    this.tabelapsisEN14 = new DataTable("tabelapsisEN14");
    this.tabelapsisEN15 = new DataTable("tabelapsisEN15");
    this.tabelapsisEN12 = new DataTable("tabelapsisEN12");

    TabelasPsis.Tables.Add("tabelapsisEN11");
    TabelasPsis.Tables.Add("tabelapsisEN13");
    TabelasPsis.Tables.Add("tabelapsisEN14");
    TabelasPsis.Tables.Add("tabelapsisEN15");
    TabelasPsis.Tables.Add("tabelapsisEN12");
```

Any hint?

Update: I'm defining the values of it in another form, not in this class, could that be the issue?

Update2: I tried to write a datatable as well using this:

```
DataAccess.Instance.TabelasPsis.WriteXml(@"C:\tabelapsis.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
DataAccess.Instance.tabelapsisEN15.WriteXml(@"C:\tabelapsis2.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

The result is: the datatable is written correctly, but the dataset isn't, what could be wrong?

Comment: First check whether that your dataset contains with data by putting a break point. If data exists, then check the code where you are exporting the dataset to xml to ensure that it contains data or not.

Comment: I made a test, i tried to write a datatable with the exactly the same method, and it worked, the datatables get written correctly. Only the dataset isnt

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you add a datatable to a dataset the way i did, you can't add the datatable names as string, or it wont recognize the datatable.

Simply do

```
TabelasPsis.Tables.Add(tabelapsisEN11);
    TabelasPsis.Tables.Add(tabelapsisEN13);
    TabelasPsis.Tables.Add(tabelapsisEN14);
    TabelasPsis.Tables.Add(tabelapsisEN15);
    TabelasPsis.Tables.Add(tabelapsisEN12);
```

and the dataset TabelasPsis will recognize the datatables with the names ahead.